# How to limit Slurm job CPU usage for users?

Tags: slurm

So, we have slurm accounting enabled, and I tried to limit CPUs for user via the command,

`sacctmgr modify user where name=username set GrpTRES=cpu=2`

But when I try to submit a job, that requests more CPUs, it still works a gives me an output, pasting the sample job here, incase that's not accurately using the resources,

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=3
sleep 5
echo "Running on $(hostname)"
```

The job details, also, show it utilizes more,

```
UserId=username(10172) GroupId=username(15173) MCS_label=N/A
   Priority=4294901746 Nice=0 Account=dev QOS=normal
   JobState=CONFIGURING Reason=None Dependency=(null)
   Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=1 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
   RunTime=00:02:30 TimeLimit=UNLIMITED TimeMin=N/A
   SubmitTime=2022-12-30T00:09:03 EligibleTime=2022-12-30T00:09:03
   AccrueTime=2022-12-30T00:09:03
   StartTime=2022-12-30T00:09:03 EndTime=Unknown Deadline=N/A
   SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0 LastSchedEval=2022-12-30T00:09:03 Scheduler=Main
   Partition=default-queue AllocNode:Sid=ip-10-125-240-24:19524
   ReqNodeList=(null) ExcNodeList=(null)
   NodeList=default-queue-dy-r6i2xlarge-1
   BatchHost=default-queue-dy-r6i2xlarge-1
   NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=6 NumTasks=2 CPUs/Task=3 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
   TRES=cpu=6,node=1,billing=6
   Socks/Node=* NtasksPerN:B:S:C=0:0:*:* CoreSpec=*
   MinCPUsNode=3 MinMemoryNode=0 MinTmpDiskNode=0
   Features=(null) DelayBoot=00:00:00
   OverSubscribe=OK Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
   Command=/shared-storage/home/username/tres-test.sh
   WorkDir=/shared-storage/home/username
   StdErr=/shared-storage/home/username/slurm-13.out
   StdIn=/dev/null
   StdOut=/shared-storage/home/username/slurm-13.out
   Power=
```

So, what am I missing?

Or is there a better way to restrict CPUs for all users in the system?

This user is created in slurm, but just curious, if I want to have the same restriction on all the users, should all of them be created in slurm, this way?

`sacctmgr create user name=username account=account_name`